# integer vector pair selection based on some equation having 0-1 solution

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Given a set of vectors $V = \{\vec{v_1}, \cdots, \vec{v_i}, \cdots, \vec{v_n}\}$ where $\vec{v_i} \in \mathbb{Z}^d$.

How can I find all pairs $ \vec{i}, \vec{j} \in V, \vec{i}\neq \vec{j}$. Such that
$$
\begin{cases}
\langle\vec{i} , \vec{x}\rangle =0 \\
 \langle\vec{j} , 1- \vec{x}\rangle =0
\end{cases}
$$

have solutions $\vec{x} \in \{0, 1\}^d$

Comment: Hint: what must be true of the $\vec i, \vec j$ for which $\vec x = \vec 0$ is a solution? What must be true of the $\vec i, \vec j$ for which $\vec x = (1, 0, 0, \dots, 0)$ is a solution? For which $(1,1, 0, 0, \dots, 0)$?

Comment: enumerating all $\vec{x}$ would have exponential complexity though $2^d$

Comment: I didn't suggest you enumerate all $\vec x$. I suggested you examine the particular cases listed and figure out what they say about $\vec i, \vec j$.

Comment: can you elaborate? I did put some effort into the decision problem, given one specific $\vec{i}, \vec{j}$ pair, checking if exists $\vec{x}$ is already exponential complexity. as this is the famous 0-1 integer linear programming feasibility problem, which is NP-complete.

Comment: And I am telling you that you need to examine it from the opposite side. For a given $\vec x$, find the $\vec i, \vec j$ that have it as a solution.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don’t get the hint, why would try a few x would help? Would really appreciate some help :)

Comment: I've given you help. But you are rejecting it without even giving it a chance. TRY IT. What can you figure out about how the $\vec i, \vec j$ are related in these cases?

Comment: Ah, after plug-in a few number it seems columns in i has to be 0, when the column in x is 1 and j is the opposite of i. So for every column, either I or J need to have a zero column

Comment: Thank you! It did helped a lot! Mind make it an answer? I’m happy to accept it!

Comment: That is what I thought at first, but it isn't correct. For example, for $\vec x = (1,1,0, \dots, 0)$, the values $\vec i = (-1,1, 50, 100, \dots)$ and $\vec j = (21, 13, 1, -1, 0, 0 \dots)$ work.

Comment: right... so it is still exponential complexity?  since even if there exists a polynomial method, that means for any $\vec{i}$, $\vec{j}$, we have decided it has 0-1 integer programming solution, which overthrows the NP-completeness

Comment: No. That was another hint. Your first idea was not quite correct. So you gotta look a little closer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119407/discussion-between-peng-yu-and-paul-sinclair).

Comment: Why is there infinite j? The set v is a finite set too.

Comment: Nevermind. I forgot you restricted it to a finite set.

Comment: yeah, thanks for the effort, really appreciate it, solving this in polynomial time would basically prove NP=P, which might be too difficult/impossible :(